# Synchronize child site calendar to parent site calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online

Iam having a requirement that i need to synchronize the root site calendar to all child site calendars in the site collection. Is there any way for that with and without coding?

Please help me on this?

Thanks,
Suresh Pydi.

Comment: NOTE: same problem here with workspace (child) calendars on the main scheduling page. The max 10 makes overlays non-viable.

Answer (score 1):

Would the Calendar Overlays help better (max. limit to 10 calendars) - these are just views of the data? Basically you could re-consider your IA differently by renaming them apropiately. The concept of Child-Parent Calendar do not exist in SharePoint, unless you build your own Event Handlers or SPD Workflows to keep 2 calendars updated.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Is it possible through Designer workflow? we have to connect child calendar to parent calendar. i.e. When ever child site calendar edited or updated, parent site calendar should be updated. There are more than 1000 child sites are there in parent site. We need to update the parent site calendar for every child site calendar edited or updated.

Comment: If the overlay is used with subsites it does this automatically for you (simple rolled-up views). If your purpose is to actually copy events from child to parent, use the Copy Item via a Workflow in SPD / the only issue would be to attach it to all calendars (use Reusable Workflow and attach to Event Content Type) and trigger it on Create and Update.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Calendar Overlay.

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.